# How do I fix this error in my Binary Search Python Code

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am learning about Binary Search in python and I decided that I want to implement it in actual code instead of just theory, so I found some examples and wrote some code. This is the code that I have written:

```
    listData = [45, 125, 133, 192, 212, 256, 281, 283, 311, 358, 418, 424, 451, 483, 503, 567, 597, 
    602, 628, 651, 652, 677, 643, 778, 800, 805, 823, 842, 930, 945]

    def binarySearch(listData, value):
        low = 0
        high = len(listData) 
    while (low <= high):
        mid = (low+high)/2
        if (listData[mid] == value):
            return mid
        elif (listData[mid] < value):
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1
    return -1

print(binarySearch(listData, 45))
```

When I run this I get an error, this is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bobby Singh\Desktop\binaryalgosearch.py", line 16, in <module>
print(binarySearch(listData, 45))
  File "C:\Users\Bobby Singh\Desktop\binaryalgosearch.py", line 8, in binarySearch
if (listData[mid] == value):
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Sorry for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Your `high` index should be `high = len(listData) - 1` since the highest index for a list is `lenght - 1`

Also, you need to round the `mid` since it can give `0.5` for cases that are odd. so do `mid = round((low+high)/2)`

Comment: You may as well simply use integer division: `mid = (low+high)//2`

Comment: And `(low+high)/2` will *always* return a float, e.g. `4/2` returns `2.0` not `2`.